# dynamic id on anchor not firing on other anchor last anchor php js pdo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

```
<div class="headerimage"><img src="images/events.png"/></div>
    <?php
    foreach (LoadEvent() as $value){
    echo '<div class="dynamicsidemenu eventback">';
    echo "<a class=\"event\"id=" .$value['eventsearchresultid']. " href='#' value=" .$value['eventsearchresultid']. ">".$value['eventsearchresultwhat']."</a>";
    echo "<br/>\n";
    echo $value['eventsearchresultwhen'];
    echo "<br/>\n";
    echo $value['eventsearchresultwhere'];
    echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $(".event").attr("value");
    var a = document.getElementById(id);
    a.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(this.getAttribute(id));
    //var $id = this.getAttribute("value");
    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/upcomingeventsmenu.php');
    $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/upcomingeventscontent.php?id=' + id );
    });
});
```

I have here a code o the last 5 entry from database each link goes to details page of each event i was able to make the first link go to detail page but the second link is not firing what is the mistake here.
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `id` inside the `click` event handler, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".event").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/upcomingeventsmenu.php');
        $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/upcomingeventscontent.php?id=' + id);
    });
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 30 seconds!

Comment: it works please explain why my code didnt work..appreciate the suggestion so much it will help me more if i know why it didnt work

Comment: 1) You want to implement an algorithm for all your `.event` elements, so before anything you should loop them. 2) The `id` is unique for each element, so getting it should be within the loop. 3) You use jQuery, but you are writing RAW javascript which is more hard than jQuery (to be crossbrowser).

Answer (score 0):

change your **anchor** tag lines like below:

```
echo "<a class=\"event\" id=\"" .$value['eventsearchresultid']."\" href=\"#\" value=\"".$value['eventsearchresultid']."\">".$value['eventsearchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

Comment: it is the same the last entry is firing but the others is not